# How to define date of today in json file? Is there any way for this?

Tags: java, json

I have a JSON file, it contains date and id:

```
[{
    "date": "2018-08-08",
    "id": 3
}]
```

I want to define value of date as `Date.now()`, for example:

```
[{
    "date": Date.now(),
    "id": 3
}]
```

How can I do this or can it be done?

***Note: I'm making the insert use this json file, 
I create json file as separate files,

example: x.json, y.json***

Comment: If I understand you right, you want to write the Date.now() expression inside a normal json file?

Comment: build the object in Java, set the values and convert it to JSON

Comment: This might help : http://www.java2novice.com/java-json/jackson/handle-date-in-json/

Comment: The direct answer is now, JSON is logical not functional. However, if your able to write the parse statements in java, all you would have to do is an if statement, if the date is empty (date:"") than set date to `Date.now()`. Otherwise, can I have more information on how the json is being parsed?

Answer (score 1):

Below `JSON` `payload` is invalid:

```
[{
    "date": Date.now(),
    "id": 3
}]
```

> ERROR: Strings should be wrapped in double quotes.[Code 17, Structure
>   5]

Generally, `JSON` schema does not allow to things like this. If you want keep `now` as information that represents time idea of `now` just create `JSON` `payload` like below:

```
[
   {
      "date":"now()",
      "id":3
   }
]
```

Since now, your client should implement custom deserialiser than whenever find `now()` text it must replaced it with `new Date()` or `DateTime.now()` or whatever it needs.

Answer (score 0):

There are several JSON parsing libraries available for Java. One of which is https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json

You read the String from your file, Parse it to JSONObject.

Iterate through the JSONArray and set the "date" field to your desired date and write it back.

Hope this answers your how part.

Answer (score 0):

JSON is a structured transport format. It does not have logic in it.

So you can not do like

```
[{
    "date": Date.now(),
    "id": 3
}]
```

but you can write your own logic eg:

```
[{
    "date": ${placeholderForDate},
    "id": 3
}]
```

You can manage this placeholder as per requirement while sending/receiving request.

you can perform this placeholder replacement in you code part after receiving request or you can handle it in UI also.